# Java do nothing

Tags: java

What is the equivalent to Python's `pass` in Java? I realize that I could use `continue` or not complete the body of a statement to achieve that effect, but I like having a `pass` statement.

Comment: An empty brace pair. `{ }`

Comment: What on earth do you use it for?

Comment: There is no strict equivalent to it (since you can `pass` on methods which normally return a value), but there are "do nothing"s. What is it that you want to do exactly? In what context?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Just use a semi-colon `;`, it has the same effect.

Answer (score 40):

If you want something noticeable, you can use

```
assert true;
```

This will allow you to have something that a reader can recognize or that can be searched for.

Comment: This seems to be the most clean answer!

Comment: I may be mistaken but `assert true` is not the same as a no-op

Comment: @user3282276 It is not the same, but an `assert true` is always performed and it is easy to identify as part of a debug statement. When there is no explicit *no-op* command it is better than an empty statement. That was the point that I was trying to make.

Comment: @user3282276 the OP wanted something to use instead of an empty statement. Since there is no no-op or pass then this can be used instead

Comment: I thought this would be great for setting breakpoint, but it got optimized out and so didn't work.

Answer (score 18):

```
;
```

`;` is the empty statement. Usually, you don't need it - you can just put nothing in the brackets for an empty loop - but it can be useful.

Answer (score 9):

I normally use something like:

```
"".isEmpty(); // do nothing
```

It's useful to be able to have a line of code which does nothing when debugging. You can put a breakpoint on that line, which is especially useful if it would usually be an empty block of code (e.g. empty catch block etc), as putting a breakpoint on an empty line can create confusion about where the breakpoint is actually set.

Comment: I think this is the most genius answer, would use this instead of a bland semicolon

Answer (score 2):

There is no (strict) equivalent since in java you have to specify the return type for the method in its declaration which is then checked against a computed type of the following the return statement. So for methods that have a return type - neither semicollon nor leaving empty braces will work;

I personally use: `throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");` - this is searchable, alerts you that the method is not implemented and is compatible with the strict return types.

Comment: don't a method with `no operation` can't throw any exceptions, because it does nothigng?

Answer (score 2):

I feel, there is no construct in Java identical to pass in Python. This is mostly because Java is a statically typed language where as Python is a dynamically typed language. More so when you are defining a method / function. In that context, the provided answers are valid / correct only for a method that returns void.

For example for a Python function

```
def function_returns_void:
    pass
```

you can have a Java method

```
public void function_returns_void(){}
```

or

```
public void function_returns_void(){;}
```

but when a method is supposed to return a value, while **pass** may still work in Python, one will stuck with compilation problem when not returning a value.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any idea of any `pass` like statement in java but I think I have a alternative for you note: does however have some inability over `pass`
`System.out.println("");`
just print an empty string and in a way *does nothing*

Comment: or just use a semi-colon `;` anything you like that does the same really...